# Why is this simple CORS GET failing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, cors

I have a server running apache. The .htaccess contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|css)$">
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Why is it that

```
$.get('https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/fonts/otama-text-regular/otamatextregular.eot')`
```

works (try it in the console from any domain), whereas

```
$.get('https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/lib/icons.data.svg.css')
```

fails with this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/lib/icons.data.svg.css. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://whatever.com' is therefore not allowed access.

And how can I get it working?

Comment: Well the second one does not return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the error message says. Are you sure that .htaccess is right/working correctly?

Comment: @user2415266 Yes, I believe htaccess is working correctly, in that the rest of the site works as expected. What does the second one return for you? The error message above was from Chrome. Firefox gives "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/lib/icons.data.svg.css. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is your regex in the FilesMatch rule, since your css file is called "icons.data.svg.css" it won't be found as ".css"

Comment: If I'm reading the regex correctly it will only match string that end in the allowed extension so the preceding icons.data.svg will not be mart of the match .. only the final .css .. so this looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing Header can be confirmed using curl:

```
 curl -v https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/fonts/otama-text-regular/otamatextregular.eot > delme.txt

 curl -v https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/lib/icons.data.svg.css > delme.txt
```

The regex should be happy with the filename so I expect that the problem is either because there is a conflicting configuration somewhere in the apache configuration. 
Another diagnostic check would be to copy the failing file into the fonts directory and check whether the header is present - this will confirm that the regex or the filename isn't the problem but indicates that it is directory configuration related.

You have stated that there are no other .htaccess files in the document root or children ( this could cause the problem ) and the file is being served just without the headers.

My feeling at this stage is that this may be related to your  mod_pagespeed which is disabled for lib/icons. It could even come down to the ordering of the modules being loaded.

Trivially I would first restart your apache just in case. Any caching or proxy infrastructure in between should be disabled. Next I would disable mod_pagespeed and see if the issue remains.

I would also check to see whether there is a block of configuration in either your httpd.conf or the virtual hosts configuration that is similar as it is possible that this is catching some directories and not others and that your .htaccess is not doing what is expected. As a further check I would try removing or temporarily renaming .htaccess (  to htaccess-removed or something similar ) to confirm that the URL request headers are no longer being included using the curl or other approaches to validating the CORS headers.

Probably not related however another  thing I'd check is the permissions and ownership of the files and directories - thought worth mentioning just in case.

Also worth checking the error logs on restarting the apache and on making the requests as this may provide further insight.

Comment: It was indeed mod_pagespeed causing the issue. Once I added `ModPagespeedDisallow "*/lib/icon*"` into my .htaccess it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the full path to your `.htaccess` file?

Ether your `.htaccess` file is not set up in a way to have it apply it's rules to files in the https://www.sarahlawrence.edu/_assets/v6/lib/ location, or there is another rule somewhere else superseding the rule you have shown above.

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the root of the server, i.e. /.htaccess. There is no other .htaccess file in the /lib/ or /fonts/ folders (or ancestor folders of those except for the one in the server root), and there is no other reference to either folder in the .htaccess except that mod_pagespeed is disabled for *lib/icons*.